# Can I use IP address in postman like (174.100.101.101)

Tags: java, spring, postman, ip-address

I want to get the IP address from request using spring boot to get the current location of user,
I am using the geoip2 dependency.
But when I'm running my application I got this error because I don't use proxy in postman:

```
com.maxmind.geoip2.exception.AddressNotFoundException: The address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 is not in the database.
```

And even when I used the IP address (127.0.0.1) I got the same error.

My question: is there any way to change the IP adress of postman to a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

You may get `address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` error because of translation `localhost` to `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` in IPv6.

If using 127.0.0.1 didn't help you - try both following options:

1. Check whether you set variable `HTTP_PROXY` in the system environment. If yes - try to remove it and restart Postman.
2. If it didn't help - set the following in your environment variables:

```
HTTP_PROXY=yourProxy:9999
HTTPS_PROXY=yourProxy:9999
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Then set System Proxy in the Postman Proxy settings section.
Restart Postman.